# Exterior measure on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I'm preparing myself for the final exam in real-analysis and I'm trying to solve this exercise.
 Show that there is no exterior measure $\mu^*$  on $\mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $\forall$ $p, q$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$ with $p<q$
$$
 \mu^*({x \in \mathbb{Q} : p\leq x\leq q})=q-p.$$

 I was thinking to suppose that there is such an exterior measure, and then I'd probably get a contradiction, but I don't know how it should be done...

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mu^{*}(\{a\})=0$ for each $a$ and $\mathbb Q$ is countable so $\mu^{*}(A)=0$ for every $A$ by countable sub-additivity of exterior measures.

Comment: Oh, I see...Thank you!